# Getting Renovator badge?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

How do I get the bronze badge **Renovator**?

This badge belongs to the **"Documentation Badges"** group.

Comment: When you try for *First improvement request of a topic or example*

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67397)*

Answer (score 1):

When you do improvement request on some topic

[image]

For whatever reason you have.

[image]